# C# Trying to figure out how to compare each item from my 2 list boxes, side by side

Tags: c#

I have listbox1 and listbox2, they each have 20 variables inside them
The first listbox has the correct answers, the second had user answers.

I'm trying to compare `listbox1.items(i)` with `listbox2.items(i)` and if equal, give a checkmark, or +1 to the grade.

But the problem is, I've read all the entries for .items, and was unable to find a way that I can select a certain one via for loops.

My initializing code to create the members of the list looks like this

```
string[] correctAnswers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path);
foreach (string value in correctAnswers)
{
    correctAnswersList.Items.Add(value);
}
string[] userAnswers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path2);
foreach (string value in userAnswers)
{
    userAnswersList.Items.Add(value);
}
```

I'm thinking I might have to do the foreach again, but again, I'm not sure how to compare two of them at the same time... If anyone can help, that would be great.

Comment: use index for your listbox because if you use item, it pertains to all the entry inside your listbox

Comment: Like this? `if (correctAnswersList.Items.IndexOf(i) == userAnswersList.Items.IndexOf(i))`

Comment: I don't have VS for now, I'm not sure but it's something like this, correctAnswersList.SelectedIndex[0].ToString() == userAnswersList.SelectedIndex[0].ToSTring();

and just put this inside a for loop or foreach, and instead of using zero, use the variable for the loop ;)

Comment: Ahh, alright - thanks, I'll try that real quick It says "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'"

Comment: Facepalm, I'm stupid, I can just use raw output from my file to compare, instead of trying to pull a specific line of my listbox >.>

Comment: Haha, at least you still found a solution :) happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the count of all non-matching elements in the list, and return that as the score. This can be done using [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908822%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Something like:

```
int score = correctAnswersList.Items.Count - correctAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>().Except(userAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>()).ToList().Count;
```

If you want case-insensitive:

```
int score = correctAnswersList.Items.Count - correctAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>().Except(userAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList().Count;
```

EDIT: Realised the above solution doesn't check in order of list, but rather compares elements regardless of order.

If order is important (which i assume it is), you can use Where instead and compare each element.

```
int score = correctAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>().Where(t => userAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>().ElementAt(correctAnswersList.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().IndexOf(t)).Equals(t)).ToList().Count;
```

Comment: I get an error under the Except part. http://prntscr.com/aoaoox I think its because Except isn't a valid listbox.extension or something

Comment: @JohnOlivas What version of .NET are you using. LINQ is only in .NET 3.5 and higher. Just add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code.

Comment: I have the using System.linq in there already, but it still showed up with the error, and I'm pretty sure I've got at least 3.5.

Comment: Thats odd, the only requirement is `System.Linq.` Maybe copy and paste your code into a paste bin, and I could have a look.

Comment: I'm pretty sure anyone else who comes by and has the same issue I am, this will help them, so I'll give you best answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had a `List` not a `Listbox`. Just means you need to access the `.Items` and then use `Cast<string>` to make it an `IEnumerable<T>` so that you can use LINQ on it. Have updated the code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0;i<correctAnswersList.Items.Count;i++)
{
    if (correctAnswersList.Items[i]==userAnswersList.Items[i]) {
        //If Matched
        // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and when I got to the function, nothing matched apparently :L Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to be able to use Mayura's result, but for whatever reason I can't get the error under Except to go away, I've got what he said I needed to be 'using', but it doesn't work.

But the way I got around it, was by doing this

```
    void compareAnswers()
    {
        string path = "C:\\DriverTest\\correctAnswers.txt";
        string path2 = "C:\\DriverTest\\userAnswers.txt";
        string[] correctAnswers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path);
        string[] userAnswers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path2);

        for (int i = 0; i != 20; i++)
        {
            if (correctAnswers[i] == userAnswers[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Answer " + (i+1) + " is correct");
                //Where this will be what I use to implement the scoring system
            }
        }
    }
```